# How to add events in Blackberry calendar

Tags: blackberry, calendar

I have a server which will send my daily plans once every day to my application i've written in blackberry. Now i want to store all those in my calendar in blackberry 8520. Is it possible? Please tell what api's i should use. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
Event _event;  
Calenderevent = "Event name";
EventList eventList = (EventList) PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.WRITE_ONLY);
_event = eventList.createEvent();
    long l = "Event date in long format";
    _event.addString(Event.SUMMARY, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE,Calenderevent);
    _event.addDate(Event.START, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, l);
    RepeatRule rule = new RepeatRule();
   rule.setInt(RepeatRule.FREQUENCY,RepeatRule.YEARLY);
_event.setRepeat(rule);
   //If you need to repeat the event then use repeatrule.
_event.commit();
```